# Channel Form - Control errors on where they should be displayed, inline or not

Tags: channel-form

I am trying to find a way to be able to control where errors show.

The native EE Channel Form feature of using `error_handling="inline"` is good for most cases but not for all.

For example, when I try to register a username/email that already exists, an error at the top displays

```
The username you chose is not available
```

or

```
The email you chose is not available
```

However, I would want these errors to be displayed inline, next to the username/email field.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using {error:custom_field_name}?

Comment: @Nutmeg I did. However, it only works for those errors that EE deems to be inline. There are some errors that can be thought of as inline but EE doesn't classify them as such(like the errors above in my example).

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't used the add-on [Freemember](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember), I am pretty sure this would do the job. Bonus it's free and has a great company behind it!

Comment: Zoo Visitor add-on also allows inline errors for these types of errors.